# How do I solve this error in .g file generated with json_annotation package

Tags: json, flutter, dart, serialization, mobile

When I run the application, I get this error:

```
Error: The argument type 'List<dynamic>' can't be assigned to the parameter 
type 'List<APIIngredients>'.
```

It looks like it is trying to convert the `ingredients` to a `dynamic` list which should be a list of `APIIngredients` but when I change the `dynamic` to `APIIngrdients`, I get another error:

```
Unhandled Exception: type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 
'List<APIIngredients>' in type cast
```

This is the generated code of `recipe_model.g.dart` file:

```dart
// GENERATED CODE - DO NOT MODIFY BY HAND

part of 'recipe_model.dart';

// **************************************************************************
// JsonSerializableGenerator
// **************************************************************************

ApiRecipeQuery _$ApiRecipeQueryFromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) =>
    ApiRecipeQuery(
      query: json['q'] as String,
      from: json['from'] as int,
      to: json['to'] as int,
      more: json['more'] as bool,
      count: json['count'] as int,
      hits: (json['hits'] as List<dynamic>)
          .map((e) => APIHits.fromJson(e as Map<String, dynamic>))
          .toList(),
    );

Map<String, dynamic> _$ApiRecipeQueryToJson(ApiRecipeQuery instance) =>
    <String, dynamic>{
      'q': instance.query,
      'from': instance.from,
      'to': instance.to,
      'more': instance.more,
      'count': instance.count,
      'hits': instance.hits,
    };

APIHits _$APIHitsFromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => APIHits(
      recipe: APIRecipe.fromJson(json['recipe'] as Map<String, dynamic>),
    );

Map<String, dynamic> _$APIHitsToJson(APIHits instance) => <String, dynamic>{
      'recipe': instance.recipe,
    };

APIRecipe _$APIRecipeFromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => APIRecipe(
      label: json['label'].toString(),
      image: json['image'].toString(),
      url: json['url'].toString(),
      ingredients: json['ingredients'] as List<dynamic>,
      calorie: (json['calorie'] as num).toDouble(),
      totalWeight: (json['totalWeight'] as num).toDouble(),
      totalTime: (json['totalTime'] as num).toDouble(),
    );

Map<String, dynamic> _$APIRecipeToJson(APIRecipe instance) => <String, dynamic>{
      'label': instance.label,
      'image': instance.image,
      'url': instance.url,
      'ingredients': instance.ingredients,
      'calorie': instance.calorie,
      'totalWeight': instance.totalWeight,
      'totalTime': instance.totalTime,
    };

APIIngredients _$APIIngredientsFromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) =>
    APIIngredients(
      name: json['text'].toString(),
      weight: (json['weight'] as num).toDouble(),
    );

Map<String, dynamic> _$APIIngredientsToJson(APIIngredients instance) =>
    <String, dynamic>{
      'text': instance.name,
      'weight': instance.weight,
    };
```

And this is my model class:

```dart
import 'package:json_annotation/json_annotation.dart';

part 'recipe_model.g.dart';

// All you need to do is to define the fields you need and the json_annotatio library will convert these fields to json
// and from json

@JsonSerializable()
class ApiRecipeQuery{
  factory ApiRecipeQuery.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json)=>_$ApiRecipeQueryFromJson(json);

  @JsonKey(name: 'q')
  String query;
  int from;
  int to;
  bool more;
  int count;
  List <APIHits> hits;

  ApiRecipeQuery({
    required this.query,
    required this.from,
    required this.to,
    required this.more,
    required this.count,
    required this.hits,
});

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$ApiRecipeQueryToJson(this);
}

@JsonSerializable()
class APIHits {
  APIRecipe recipe;

  APIHits({required this.recipe});
   factory APIHits.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => _$APIHitsFromJson(json);

   Map<String, dynamic> toJson()=>_$APIHitsToJson(this);
}


@JsonSerializable()
class APIRecipe {

  String label;
  String image;
  String url;
  List<APIIngredients> ingredients;
  double calorie;
  double totalWeight;
  double totalTime;

  APIRecipe({
    required this.label,
    required this.image,
    required this.url,
    required this.ingredients,
    required this.calorie,
    required this.totalWeight,
    required this.totalTime,
});

  factory APIRecipe.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic>json) => _$APIRecipeFromJson(json);

  Map<String, dynamic> Function(APIRecipe instance) toJson() => _$APIRecipeToJson;

  // Converts the calorie into a string
  String getCalories(double? calorie){
    if( calorie == null){
      return '0 KCAl';
    }
    return '${calorie.floor()} KCAl';
  }

  // Cinvert the weight into a string
  String getWeight( double? weight){
    if(weight == null) {
      return '0g';
    }
    return '${weight.floor()}g';
  }
}


@JsonSerializable()
class APIIngredients {

  @JsonKey(name: 'text')
  String name;
  double weight;

  APIIngredients({
    required this.name,
    required this.weight,
});

  factory APIIngredients.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => _$APIIngredientsFromJson(json);

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$APIIngredientsToJson(this);
}
```

I changed the `dynamic` in the `ingredients` field in the `_$APIRecipeFromJson` inside the `recipe_model.g.dart` file to `APIIngredient` but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to regenerate the .g file again.
Use this command `flutter pub run build_runner build --delete-conflicting-outputs` to regenerate the file. And don't update the .g file by hand.
Once you run this command it will regenerate the .g file.

```
// GENERATED CODE - DO NOT MODIFY BY HAND

part of 'ingredient.dart';

// **************************************************************************
// JsonSerializableGenerator
// **************************************************************************

ApiRecipeQuery _$ApiRecipeQueryFromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) =>
    ApiRecipeQuery(
      query: json['q'] as String,
      from: json['from'] as int,
      to: json['to'] as int,
      more: json['more'] as bool,
      count: json['count'] as int,
      hits: (json['hits'] as List<dynamic>)
          .map((e) => APIHits.fromJson(e as Map<String, dynamic>))
          .toList(),
    );

Map<String, dynamic> _$ApiRecipeQueryToJson(ApiRecipeQuery instance) =>
    <String, dynamic>{
      'q': instance.query,
      'from': instance.from,
      'to': instance.to,
      'more': instance.more,
      'count': instance.count,
      'hits': instance.hits.map((e) => e.toJson()).toList(),
    };

APIHits _$APIHitsFromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => APIHits(
      recipe: APIRecipe.fromJson(json['recipe'] as Map<String, dynamic>),
    );

Map<String, dynamic> _$APIHitsToJson(APIHits instance) => <String, dynamic>{
      'recipe': instance.recipe.toJson(),
    };

APIRecipe _$APIRecipeFromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => APIRecipe(
      label: json['label'] as String,
      image: json['image'] as String,
      url: json['url'] as String,
      ingredients: (json['ingredients'] as List<dynamic>)
          .map((e) => APIIngredients.fromJson(e as Map<String, dynamic>))
          .toList(),
      calorie: (json['calorie'] as num).toDouble(),
      totalWeight: (json['total_weight'] as num).toDouble(),
      totalTime: (json['total_time'] as num).toDouble(),
    );

Map<String, dynamic> _$APIRecipeToJson(APIRecipe instance) => <String, dynamic>{
      'label': instance.label,
      'image': instance.image,
      'url': instance.url,
      'ingredients': instance.ingredients.map((e) => e.toJson()).toList(),
      'calorie': instance.calorie,
      'total_weight': instance.totalWeight,
      'total_time': instance.totalTime,
    };

APIIngredients _$APIIngredientsFromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) =>
    APIIngredients(
      name: json['text'] as String,
      weight: (json['weight'] as num).toDouble(),
    );

Map<String, dynamic> _$APIIngredientsToJson(APIIngredients instance) =>
    <String, dynamic>{
      'text': instance.name,
      'weight': instance.weight,
    };
```